# Падение шара по ступенькам: не получается стереть предыдущий "кадр"

Tags: java

Добрый день.

Есть задача сделать программу, в которой по нажатию кнопки шар скатывается до последней ступени и вновь появляется сверху, повторяя пройденный путь. Бесконечно. Листинг:

**Обновлено!!!**

/
 ** StepApp.java*
 /

package step;

import org.jdesktop.application.Application;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 ** The main class of the application.*
 /
class StepApp extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    private Image img;
    Button go=new Button("Go");
    Button pict=new Button("Picture");
    Button exit=new Button("Exit");

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int i = 40;
int f = 10;
int k = 40;
int h = 59;

StepApp()
{
    setLayout(null);

    add(go);
    add(pict);
    add(exit);
    go.addActionListener(this);
    pict.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    go.setBounds(130, 365, 60, 20);
    pict.setBounds(195, 365, 60, 20);
    exit.setBounds(260, 365, 60, 20);

    prepareImage(img,this);
}

    public void repaint (long tm) {

    Graphics g2 =getGraphics();
               g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g2.fillOval(f, h, k, i);
                f=f+10;

    }

     public void repaint2 (long tm) {

    Graphics g2 =getGraphics();
                f=f-10;
                g2.setColor(Color.white);
                g2.fillOval(f, h, k, i);
                h=h+50;
                f=f+50;
                 g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g2.fillOval(f, h, k, i);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

    {      if (e.getSource()==go){
               for (int k=1;k<=4;k++)

    {

               for (int j=1;j<=1;j++){
                try {
                    repaint  (100);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    repaint2 (200);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(StepApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                }

    }}
         if(e.getSource()==pict)

          {
              Graphics g =getGraphics();

              g.setColor(Color.blue);
                b=b+100;
                c=c+50;
                d=d+100;
              g.drawLine(a, b, c, d);

              for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                a=a+50;
                b=b+50;
                c=c+50;
                d=d+50;
                g.drawLine(a, b, c, d);
              }

          }

         if(e.getSource()==exit)
            System.exit(0);  
     }

 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
     StepApp fr=new StepApp();
     fr.resize(400, 400);
     fr.setVisible(true);

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

стало интересно, запустил даже... трудно назвать это "скачивание", скорее фигня =)

```
 if (e.getSource()==go) {
            for (int j=1; j<=4; j++) {
                repaint (200);
            }
        }
```

тут ты просто рисуешь 4 круга, а надо рисовать 1, потом рисовать его же ниже и тд. тогда старая картинка будет пропадать и будет похоже на анимацию. Все это лучше делать в новом потоке.

Comment: обновил код. не могу понять, получается поток здесь в роли таймера работает?

Comment: заработало! благодарю!

Comment: только теперь появилась проблема, чтобы заново начал)))

Comment: for (int j=1;j<=1;j++){
            try {
                repaint  (100);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                repaint2 (200);
            }
                   }         catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(StepApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


2 разных repaint() - так не правильно, надо сделать один, только с правильным набором параметров. А что бы начать заново, просто по окончания цикла, поставь условие - начать заново =)